# Disable webview2 download progress bar in tauri application

Tags: download, dialog, progress-bar, webview2, tauri

I am converting a single page front-end website to desktop application using tauri toolchain. When I download an image or any other file in the application, it displays a download progress bar in the top right corner. I have to disable the progress bar. When I searched how to disable it in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2downloadstartingeventargs.handled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.902.49#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2downloadstartingeventargs-handled) webview2 documentation, it suggested that I can set the `CoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs.Handled` property to `true` which will hide the download progress dialog. But I can't find how to set that property in my tauri application source code. I have included my project directory and the all the codes that I have included so far. It will be helpful for me if someone could explain how to set that property to `true` so that I can hide how to hide the progress bar in my application.

Project Folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rT_uaH6Ki_B2Hpud0SsI9ZUNZMZpmUWD?usp=sharing

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/flowers-276014_960_720.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="500">
        <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/flowers-276014_960_720.jpg" download="image.jpg">
            <button type="button">Download</button>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

RUST main file:

```
#![cfg_attr(
  all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
  windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

fn main() {
  tauri::Builder::default()
    .run(tauri::generate_context!())
    .expect("error while running tauri application");
}
```

tauri.conf configuration file:

```
{
  "build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "",
    "beforeDevCommand": "",
    "devPath": "../assets",
    "distDir": "../assets"
  },
  "package": {
    "productName": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "all": true
    },
    "bundle": {
      "active": true,
      "category": "DeveloperTool",
      "copyright": "",
      "deb": {
        "depends": []
      },
      "externalBin": [],
      "icon": [
        "icons/32x32.png",
        "icons/128x128.png",
        "icons/128x128@2x.png",
        "icons/icon.icns",
        "icons/icon.ico"
      ],
      "identifier": "com.tauri.dev",
      "longDescription": "",
      "macOS": {
        "entitlements": null,
        "exceptionDomain": "",
        "frameworks": [],
        "providerShortName": null,
        "signingIdentity": null
      },
      "resources": [],
      "shortDescription": "",
      "targets": "all",
      "windows": {
        "certificateThumbprint": null,
        "digestAlgorithm": "sha256",
        "timestampUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "security": {
      "csp": null
    },
    "updater": {
      "active": false
    },
    "windows": [
      {
        "fullscreen": false,
        "height": 600,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "Test",
        "width": 800
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer [here](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/5454)

I added the following dependencies to my Cargo.toml file

```
webview2-com = "0.19"
windows = "0.39"
```

Then in my main.rs, I added a setup hook to the Builder with the following content

```
#![cfg_attr(
  all(not(debug_assertions), target_os = "windows"),
  windows_subsystem = "windows"
)]

use tauri::Manager;
use webview2_com::{
    DownloadStartingEventHandler, Microsoft::Web::WebView2::Win32::ICoreWebView2_4,
};
use windows::{core::Interface, Win32::System::WinRT::EventRegistrationToken};

fn main() {

tauri::Builder::default()
  .setup(|app| {
    let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();

    #[cfg(windows)]
    window.with_webview(|webview| unsafe {
                let mut _token = EventRegistrationToken::default();

                let core = webview
                    .controller()
                    .CoreWebView2()
                    .unwrap()
                    .cast::<ICoreWebView2_4>()
                    .unwrap();

                let handler =
                    DownloadStartingEventHandler::create(Box::new(move |_, args| {
                        if let Some(args) = args {
                            // i don't know how safe that unwrap is, so you may wanna handle errors
                            // or just ignore them with `let _ = args.SetHandled(true);`
                            args.SetHandled(true).unwrap();
                        }
                        Ok(())
                    }));

                let _ = core.add_DownloadStarting(&handler, &mut _token);
            });

    Ok(())
  })
  .run(tauri::generate_context!())
  .expect("error while running tauri application");

}
```